# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I uninstall and install the NPM using the command

```
npm install
```

and getting error after this
I also tried

```
npm audit fix --force
```

after that the error come

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'Minus' of undefined
See "/private/var/folders/8n/6vsx9lx93lx9wrgxm1q_yv4c0000gn/T/ng-pMlA9a/angular-errors.log" for further details.
npm ERR! Test failed. See above for more details.
```

Comment: This resolved for me "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force"

Comment: @CodeSpy It actually gives me an error! invalid tag name --allow dirty. Any help?

Answer (score 18):

got same error. it's bug in new version of @angular/compiler-cli
fixed by downgrade version to "10.0.12"

UPD. checked on new version "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1" - works fine

Comment: thank you the error resolve but here new error come 
   "An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist"

Comment: Afte fixing all above errors i am getting this error
"ERROR in Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Answer (score 11):

I had to run the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

And then remove the line

```
"es5BrowserSupport": true
```

from the

```
angular.json
```

file.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

This is what I've done, clearly says in the terminal:

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

```
ng update @angular/core
```

```
ng update rxjs
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a little bit weird, but **yarn install** instead of npm install did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try updating to latest versions of all the dependencies in package.json. I faced the same issue and spent 2 weeks finding the right solution. Do "ng update" and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I used the latest version of `@angular/compiler`

```
npm install --save-dev  @angular/compiler
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove ~ and ^ before version numbers from anything related to angular framework and install again.

For example this is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/bazel": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/cdk": "10.1.0",
  "@angular/common": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/core": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/forms": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/localize": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.0.5",
  "@angular/router": "10.0.5",
  ......
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1000.4",
  "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "0.1000.4",
  "@angular/cli": "10.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.0.5",
  .....
}
```